# Python: Dump whole list in a variable

Tags: python, arrays, edid

I have this code:

```
def write_extension(self):

    extension = []
    dtd = ""
    if extension == []:
            extension = extension.extend(self.edids[]  (Thanks to Howardyan for making it clearer for me)

    print(extension)
```

I want to write the complete array in the new array `extension` but i dont know how. Is there an easy way doing this? Later on (when `extension` is not empty) i just want to add the array to the end of the `extension` array.

To Make it clear. Now i have this:

- Name1 = [1, 2, 3]
- Name2 = [4, 5, 6]
- Name3 = [7, 8, 9]

And i want to have this after i added all arrays to `extension`

extension = [123, 456, 789]

Comment: Seriously Guys, why are you downvoting my question? It may be a bit stupid/easy but i need help and i cant find a valid solution for this problem. I want to learn and thats why im asking here. I could also say im just back to bed...

Comment: I did not downvote, but it is expected that you have learned the basics of the language before asking here. If you would have done that, you would at least know that Python does not have arrays. There is a similar but more featue-rich type called `list`.

Comment: You know that even "Professional" programmers call it Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extension's type is str. cannot add with a list.
you need do this:

```
def write_extension(self):

    extension = []
    dtd = ""
    if extension == []:
            extension = extension.extend(self.edids[:])
            print(extension)
```

Comment: Doesn't work like expected... `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: modified. self.edids[:]

Answer (score 1):

You can join all the elements in your individual lists, and then extend from extension like so:

```
name1 = [1, 2, 3]
name2 = [4, 5, 6]
name3 = [7, 8, 9]
extension = []
    
''.join(map(str, name1))
''.join(map(str, name2))
''.join(map(str, name3))

extension.extend((name1, name2, name3))

>>> [123, 456, 789]
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, i will try it later on but im not quite sure if it's what i link to have/desire. Thanks for that Python correction but i guess we all had typos in our code/something else. But i dont get it why just downvote and steal my fun for programming ( So i quite new and young) so it would be a better idea to help me improve my post format skills. So all young programmers are the future and we should help them not drown them.

Comment: A very basic Question... What du you mean with `''.join(map(str, name1))`? Which Opject do need to take?